# Regrouping identique tuple values

Tags: python, tuples, grouping

I have such an input:

```
foo = (("a", "foo", "bar"), ("a", "foo", "baz"), ("b", "foo", "bar"))
```

I want to get this

```
(("a", "foo", ["bar", "baz"]), ("b", "foo", ["bar"]))
```

how can I achieve this in python?

Thanks

Comment: Write down your logic of grouping and add what you've tried so far!

Comment: Create a dictionary whose keys are the tuple elements that you want to group on, and values are the lists of the other element.

Comment: Where would `"a", "bar", "foo"` go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by the first 2 elements, then put all the grouped last elements in a list.

try this:

```py
from itertools import groupby

foo = (("a", "foo", "bar"), ("a", "foo", "baz"), ("b", "foo", "bar"))

result = tuple((*k, [t[-1] for t in g]) for k,g in groupby(foo, lambda t: t[:2]))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
(('a', 'foo', ['bar', 'baz']), ('b', 'foo', ['bar']))
```

Comment: note: groupby assumes your iterable already sorted by groups. if that's not the case,the defaultdict method will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists to group with key as the first two items from each tuple, and the value as the third item. Then you can transform this result into a tuple of tuples for your final result.

```
from collections import defaultdict

foo = (("a", "foo", "bar"), ("a", "foo", "baz"), ("b", "foo", "bar"))

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y, z in foo:
    d[x, y].append(z)

print(tuple((*k, v) for k, v in d.items()))
# (('a', 'foo', ['bar', 'baz']), ('b', 'foo', ['bar']))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need something without importing any package:

```
foo = (("a", "foo", "bar"), ("a", "foo", "baz"), ("b", "foo", "bar"))
d = {}
for *key, val in foo:
        d[tuple(key)] = d.get(tuple(key),[]) + [val]
print(tuple((*key,val) for key,val in d.items()))
# (('a', 'foo', ['bar', 'baz']), ('b', 'foo', ['bar']))
```